# Empty lines between chess boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a chess board.

I have these lines that are white. If I do a styling on the div it will be applied to the whole div.

How can I fill those empty white spaces so it looks like a real chessboard?

```js
function drawChessBoard(){
    var para = document.createElement("html");
    var body = document.createElement("body");
    para.appendChild(body);
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var cb = document.createElement('chessboard');
    body.appendChild(cb);
    for (var row = 1; row <= 8; row++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        cb.appendChild(div);
        for (let col = 1; col <= 8; col++) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            div.appendChild(span);
            if (row % 2 === 1 && col % 2 === 1){
                span.className = "white";
            } else if (row % 2 === 1 && col % 2 === 0) {
                              span.className = "black";
            }
           else if (row % 2 === 0 && col % 2 === 0) {
                span.className = 'white';
            }   else{
                              span.className = "black";
        }
    }
}
}
drawChessBoard();
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}
.white {
  display:inline-block;
  width:4em;
  height:4em;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
.black {
  display:inline-block;
  width:4em;
  height:4em;
  background-color: brown;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget rescaling. When making your chessboard less wide, the tiles collaps in to rows of e.g. 6 wide and 2 wide.

Answer (score 3):

Give all the cells (the `<span>` elements) `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
.white, .black{ vertical-align: middle; }
```

Alternatively, you can use `float: left` instead of `vertical-align`

---

I would advise you *not* to have separate rows in your HTML markup, but simply place all the DOM nodes flat in their container, so you'll have `8x8` elements and then style it so you'll have only `8` per row:

[How do I make a responsive grid with a checkered pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57551296/104380)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:
When using `inline-block` you have to use vertical alignment in case the content of the inline-block element is filled.

```js
function drawChessBoard() {
  var para = document.createElement("html");
  var body = document.createElement("body");
  para.appendChild(body);
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var cb = document.createElement('chessboard');
  body.appendChild(cb);
  for (var row = 1; row <= 8; row++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    cb.appendChild(div);
    for (let col = 1; col <= 8; col++) {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      div.appendChild(span);
      if (row % 2 === 1 && col % 2 === 1) {
        span.className = "white";
      } else if (row % 2 === 1 && col % 2 === 0) {
        span.className = "black";
      } else if (row % 2 === 0 && col % 2 === 0) {
        span.className = 'white';
      } else {
        span.className = "black";
      }
    }
  }
}
drawChessBoard();
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.white {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: orange;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px solid brown;
}

.black {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: brown;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lr8dve0/)